# domain redirect without changing url

Tags: asp.net, windows, sql-server-2005, iis-7

I'm building a sitebuilder project. The database and all other ASP.NET code is ready but I don't know how to handle domain names, because I will have only one site in IIS7 but more than a hundred sites are gonna publish from my site. (Like the sitebuilder you can find on the internet.) When users go the page, ex: `www.myname1.com`, it will be published from my site but the URL that the user wrote will be protected, so the user never understand the behind.
(The site is coded in ASP.NET 2.0 and the hosting environment is Windows Server 2008 so IIS7.)
I need some advice where to start. Thanks.

Comment: Cleaned up your post, but I still don't understand. What does "the user never understand the behind" mean? Do you mean, users shouldn't know that `www.myname1.com` is being published by my server?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I understand you, but if you configure a [host header](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx) for each site, you can assign more than one site to a single IP address.  Is that what you're trying to do?